# PHP with 2 conditions where 1 or the other can be true

Tags: php

I have two conditions. What I want to happen is if either of the conditions quantities are greater than zero then the appropriate message displays. What is happening is the messages are displaying only if `_minLogo` is greater than zero.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `foreach( ($this->_minLogo) || ($this->_minFreeLogo)`? `foreach(not-an-array as $value)`?

Comment: @Wrikken See kingkero's answer, and my note about JS. It's not that unreasonable a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, should have refreshed after trying to figure out what that would do in PHP, I'm actually embarrassed it took me this long, sorry ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have a comparison `$this->_minLogo || $this->_minFreeLogo` - the result of this is a boolean! And you can't iterate over a boolean. Use something like this

```
if ($this->_minLogo || $this->_minFreeLogo) {
    if ($this->_minLogo)
        $set = $this->_minLogo;
    else
        $set = $this->_minFreeLogo;
    foreach ($set as $logo_type => $quantity) {
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah didn't even notice he was doing that, I only saw the conditional. good catch.

Comment: Well spotted. :) Worth noting that some languages (JS comes to mind) will return the "truthy" value when executing a `boolean or` like this (`param = param || default` is quite common). It doesn't work in PHP, because both sides of the expression are cast to boolean before the comparison takes place, so the result is only ever `true` or `false`.

Comment: @kingkero thanks this looks like it should work, but sadly it doesn't and i can't see or workout why :(

Comment: (Please add the answers to this to your original question) What exactly is it you are trying to do? Are `_minLogo` and `_minFreeLogo` always arrays (or other constructs that can be iterated over)? Also why are you working with `_minFreeLogo` inside the loop if the possibility is that this is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Are either of those values guaranteed to be an integer? If statements can use integers and 'truthy' values (anything not 0 or NULL I think).

Anyways I think its better to be more specific in this case:

```
( ($this->_minLogo)  > 0 || ($this ->_minFreeLogo) > 0)
```